# R search accross similarity sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I've got a big sparse occurrence matrix that contains product similarity data.
All the products appear in the same order on both the x and y and a value of 1 means that the products are the same whether a value of 0 means that the products are different.

As follows:

```
P1  P2  P3  P4
P1  1   1   0   0
P2  0   1   0   1
P3  0   0   1   1
P4  0   1   0   1
```

In this case P1 is similar to itself and to P2 but P2 is similar to P4. So finally P1, P2 and P4 are the same.
I need to write something in R that will assign to P1, P2 and P4 the same code as follow:

```
Product_Name  Ref_Code 
     P1          P1
     P2          P1
     P3          P3
     P4          P1
```

Is it possible to do it in R?

Cheers,

Dario.

Comment: Isn't P3 similar to P4? It makes all same as per the logic.

Comment: Sorry copying and pasting has altered the original idea. P3 should not be similar to anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Prem, as per your logic, all products are the same. I have provided a code example using `reshape2`package to put your products into long format. Even though your similarity measure does not create any difference between the products, you might use the ouput from `melt()`, to sort and filter the data in a different way regarding similarity and thereby achieve what you want.

```
library(reshape2)

data <- read.table ( text = "P1  P2  P3  P4
                          P1  1   1   0   0
                          P2  0   1   0   1
                          P3  0   0   1   1
                          P4  0   1   0   1"
                          , header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


data <-cbind(rownames(data), data)
names(data)[1] <- "product1"

data.melt <- melt(data
             , id.vars = "product1"
             , measure.vars = colnames(data)[2:ncol(data)]
             , variable.name = "product2"
             , value.name = "similarity"
             ,factorsAsStrings = TRUE)

#check the output of melt, maybe the long format is suitable for your task    
data.melt

#if you split the data by your similarity and check the unique products
#in each list, you will see that they are all the same
data.split <- split(data.melt, data.melt$similarity)

lapply(data.split, function(x) {

  unique(unlist(x[, c("product1", "product2")]))


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
#sample data (to understand this approach better I have slightly modified your input data)
mat <- Matrix(data = c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1), nrow = 5, ncol = 5,
              dimnames = list(c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"),c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5")),
              sparse = TRUE)
mat

#create dataframe having relationship among similar products
mat_summary <- summary(mat)
df <- data.frame(Product_Name = rownames(mat)[mat_summary$i],
                 Similar_Product_Name = colnames(mat)[mat_summary$j])
df <- df[df$Product_Name != df$Similar_Product_Name, ]
df

#clustering - to get the final result
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
df.g <- graph.data.frame(df)
final_df <- setNames(setDT(as.data.frame(clusters(df.g)$membership), keep.rownames = TRUE)[], c('Product', 'Product_Cluster'))
final_df
```

output is:

```
   Product Product_Cluster
1:      P1               1
2:      P4               1
3:      P2               1
4:      P3               2
5:      P5               2
```